# Android, draw clock with offset from center

Tags: android, watch-face-api

I am trying to achieve this WatchFace using Android API:

[image: ScreenShot of desired watch face]

These are my paints used for Hours, Minutes and Seconds:

```
secondsPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
secondsPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
secondsPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
secondsPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
secondsPaint.setStrokeWidth(3f);
secondsPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
minutesPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
minutesPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
minutesPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
minutesPaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);
hoursPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
hoursPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
hoursPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
hoursPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
hoursPaint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
```

I have implemented the following code to draw the background, the seconds, minutes and hours:

```
// Background
canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, null);
```

Then I draw the hours and minutes

```
// Draw the minute and hour hands.
float minX = (float) Math.sin(minRot) * minLength;
float minY = (float) -Math.cos(minRot) * minLength;
canvas.drawLine(centerX, centerY, centerX + minX, centerY + minY, minutesPai
float hrX = (float) Math.sin(hrRot) * hrLength;
float hrY = (float) -Math.cos(hrRot) * hrLength;
canvas.drawLine(centerX, centerY, centerX + hrX, centerY + hrY, hoursPaint);
```

And finally the seconds

```
// draw seconds
float secX = (float) Math.sin(secRot) * secLength;
float secY = (float) -Math.cos(secRot) * secLength;
canvas.drawLine(centerX, centerY, centerX + secX, centerY + secY, secondsPaint);
```

I need to:

- create a circle in the middle of the screen and move the hours,
  minutes and seconds with few pixels from the center like the picture
  displayed.
- Make the seconds and minutes more "smooth" cause
  anti-aliasing is set but it does not work as expected

At the moment the result is the following:

[image: Actual WatchFace]

Comment: I didn't think about this solution ... Interesting and way easier approach. I will give it a shot now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To draw a circle is as just as easy as using `drawCircle()`.
So, the dirty trick could be to draw the white one and another bigger one (and maybe even a smaller one) of the same background color to cover the portion of the minutes and second hands.

So, being drawn **after** the hands, these circles will **cover** the portion you want to hide.

A very cheap trick (no other trigonometry involved).
Works for sure.

You could even use a layer-list drawable to overlay in the center... ;)

But [drawCircle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawCircle%28float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) is quite straightforward, I guess.

Comment: Tested and works perfectly, I just made a layering of multiple circles with FILL and STROKE. Wow so easy solution and didn't think about it :-)

Comment: @MD My Dear!! Nice to meet you!

Comment: @Raffaeu ... were you skeptical? I told you: a dirty trick (not so dirty, after all) is meant to work. This one in particular can save some calculations, so, it's even possibly *faster* than `properly drawn` clock hands. ;)

Comment: @DerGolem I was not, and actually by using some 'tricks' the watch face is faster than playing around with plenty of trigonometry functions. :-)

Comment: I'm always on the hunt for optimizations. Even a single 0.001 ns matters for me. I'm old-school, I was grown so. :)=

Comment: @DerGolem That's why you suggested [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30756052/database-causes-app-to-crash/30756103?noredirect=1#comment49566079_30756103](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30756052/database-causes-app-to-crash/30756103?noredirect=1#comment49566079_30756103). `You're best Code Optimizer.`

Comment: @MD Exactly, my friend, exactly. You can't even imagine the deadly jumps I do. (inverse for using -- instead of ++, multiplications and divisions by powers of 2 using << and >> respectively, multiplications by a precalculated 1/n instead of divisions by n, ...) `;)`